# Rolling maps and parallel transport

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose we have an Riemannian manifold $M$ endowed with Levi-Civita connection. Further, let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two sub-manifold, which are isometrically embedded in $M$. We let $M_1$ roll over $M_2$ along a curve $\sigma_2:[0,T]\rightarrow M_2$. I found two notions of rolling map:

[On this paper](http://www.kybernetika.cz/content/2016/2/209/paper.pdf) the rolling map should satisfy (Definition 2.1 on the paper):

**Definition 1:**

**Rolling:** Suppose $g:[0,T]\rightarrow \text{Iso}(M)$, then

1. $g(t)\sigma_2(t)\in M_1$
2. $T_{g(t)\sigma_2(t)}(M_1)=T_{g(t)\sigma_2(t)}(g(t)M_2)$

Further let $\sigma_1:[0,T]\rightarrow M_1$

**No slipping**

3. $\sigma_1'(t)=g(t)_*\sigma'_2(t)$ ($g(t)_* $ is the push-forward)

**No twist**

4. $(g'(t)g^{-1}(t))_*T_{\sigma_1(t)}M_1\subset T_{\sigma_1(t)}^\bot M_1$
5. $(g'(t)g^{-1}(t))_*T^\bot_{\sigma_1(t)}M_1\subset T_{\sigma_1(t)}M_1$

**Definition 2:**

Alternatively, if we replace $M_2$ as the tangent space of $M$ at origin $T_oM_1$, the rolling map can be defined by parallel transport $\Gamma_0^s$ by along the curve $\sigma_1(t)$ satisfying $$\sigma_1'(s)=\Gamma_0^s(\sigma_1(s))\sigma'_2(s)\tag{2}$$

**Question:**

1. It is clear that the definition of parallel transport and the condition (2) replaces the condition 3,4,5 in the first part. However, how is the condition 1,2 in the Definition 1 satisfied by Definition 2?
2. Does the Definition 2 work if we replace the tangent space $T_oM_1$ with an arbitrary sub manifold $M_2$?